# how to replace an occurance with a value which varies with each row

Tags: regex, notepad++

From research I found how to replace an occurrence with a constant value but how to replace the value of a variable with the value of preceding variable in each row where values of both the variable keep changing for every row in notepad++.

eg:

```
line1: a=sddfs, b=fegsdfs, c=ewresfs  
line2: a=oreot, b=hdrtytggs, c=fgdfgsdf
```

should be changed to

```
line1: a=sddfs, b=sddfs, c=ewresfs  
line2: a=oreot, b=oreot, c=fgdfgsdf
```

i.e, b value of every line should be changed to the corresponding value of a in that line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should try to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, you should give more details of the format of each line because regex is strict about format.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming `line1:` and `line2:` are not part of the file**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(a=(\w+), b=)\w+`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
(           : start group 1
  a=        : literally a=
  (         : start group 2
    \w+     : 1 or more word characters (the value after a=)
  )         : end group 2
  , b=      : literally
)           : end group 1
\w+         : 1 or more word characters (the value after b=)
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : the value of group 1
$2      : the value of group 2
```

**Result for given example:**

```
a=sddfs, b=sddfs, c=ewresfs  
a=oreot, b=oreot, c=fgdfgsdf
```